# How to prove that given CDF is valid?

Tags: probability

I have a CDF
$$
   F_Y(y) =
   \begin{cases}
    \displaystyle 0 & \text{for } y < 0 \\
     \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \dfrac{(\lambda A)^n}{n!} e^{-\lambda A} G_n(y)&\text{for } y \geq 0     
   \end{cases}
$$

---

where the function $G_n(y)$  is defined as

\begin{eqnarray*}
   G_n(y)
   & = &
   \begin{cases}
    \displaystyle 1 & \text{if $  n \leq 0 $} \\
    F_Z(y)&\text{if  $ n =1 $} \\
    (G_{n-1}*dF_{Z})(y) & \text{if $ n \geq 2 $}    
   \end{cases}
  \end{eqnarray*}

---

and $F_Z(z)$ is

\begin{eqnarray*}
   F_Z(z)
   & = &\dfrac{1}{A}
   \begin{cases}
    \displaystyle \pi z^{\frac{2}{2.7}} & \text{for $0 \leq z \leq  \left(\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\right)^{2.7}$} \\
    \pi z^{\frac{2}{2.7}} - 6B_2 & \text{for $ \left(\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\right)^{2.7} \leq z \leq 1$} \\
    A & \text{for $ z \geq 1  $}
   \end{cases}
  \end{eqnarray*}

```
        where
```

\begin{eqnarray*}
    B_2 & = &   z^{\frac{2}{2.7}} \arccos \left( \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2z^{1/2.7}}\right)  - \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\left( \sqrt{4z^{\frac{2}{2.7}}-3}\right) 
   \end{eqnarray*}

I'm trying to prove that $F_Y(y)$ is valid. It is becoming complicated when I consider $n\geq 2$. So, I want to consider up to $n=1$, then the equation looks like this
\begin{eqnarray*}
  F_\mathcal{Y}(y) 
  & = & e^{-\lambda A}+ \dfrac{(\lambda A)^1}{1!} e^{-\lambda A}  F_{Z}(y)
  \end{eqnarray*}

If I try to plot this CDF, I got this:
[image: CDF plot of the above expression]

It never reaches $1$. I don't know where I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: What is $A$? An arbitrary matrix?

Comment: When you only consider $n$ up to $1$, you do not have the CDF, so you cannot reasonable expect that the CDF goes to $1$.

Comment: I know the theorems, but I didn't know if the conditions were met. And the only thing left for you is to show that $F_Z$ is increasing. Furthermore, I would like to suggest to clean the comment section a bit.

Comment: $F_Z(z)$ is increasing in the interval [0,1]. If $ z \geq 1 $ , then $F_Z(z)$ tends to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We start with $G_n(y) \to 1$ as $y \to \infty$.

For $n=0$ and $n=1$ we have $G_n(y) \to 1$ as $y \to \infty$.
Suppose that $G_n(y) \to 1$ as $y \to \infty$. We have 
$$ G_{n+1}(y) = \int_{y-1}^y G_n(x) F_Z'(y-x) \textrm{d}x = - G_n(x) F_Z(y-x) |_{x=y-1}^{x=y} + \int_{y-1}^y G_n'(x)F_Z(y-x) \textrm{d}x.$$
So if we take the limit of $y \to \infty$ we have for the first term on the RHS
$$\lim_{y \to \infty}- G_n(y) F_Z(0) + G_n(y-1) F_Z(1)  = \lim_{y \to \infty} 0 + G_n(y-1) = 1.$$
For the second term we have
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{y \to \infty} | \int_{y-1}^{y}G_n'(x) F_Z(y-x) \textrm{d}x| &\le& \lim_{y \to \infty}  \int_{y-1}^y |G_n'(x)| |F_Z(y-x)| \textrm{d}x \\
&\le& \lim_{y \to \infty} \| F_Z\|_\infty \int_{y-1}^y |G_n'(x)| \textrm{d}x \\
&=&\| F_Z\|_\infty \lim_{y \to \infty}  \sup_{x \in [y-1,y]} \{|G_n'(x)|\} \\
&=&0
\end{eqnarray}
Where the limit is $0$ as $G_n(y) \to 1$ as $y \to \infty$ implies $G_n'(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$.
So we see $\lim_{y \to \infty}  G_{n+1}(y) = 1$.

Thus we see that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \lim_{y \to \infty} \frac{(\lambda A)^n}{n!}G_n(y) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(\lambda A)^n}{n!} = e^{\lambda A}$.

So if we show that we can interchange limits and summation, we are done.

We will show that $G_n$ is increasing if $F_Z$ is increasing.
We have $G_0$ and $G_1$ are increasing as $F_Z$ is increasing.
Now suppose that $G_n$ is increasing. Let $y \le z$. Then we have 
\begin{eqnarray}
G_{n+1}(z) -G_{n+1}(y) &=& \int_0^1 (G_n(z-x)-G_n(y-x))F_Z'(x) \textrm{d}x
\end{eqnarray}
As $z-x \ge y-x$ for all $x\in [0,1]$ and $G_n$ is increasing, we have $G_n(z-x)-G_n(y-x) \ge 0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$. Furthermore, as $F_Z$ is increasing, we have $F_Z'(x) \ge 0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.
So we have $G_{n+1}(z) - G_{n+1}(y) \ge 0$ for all $y \le z$, and so $G_{n+1}$ is increasing.

So we have that $n \mapsto G_n(y)$ is bounded by $1$ for all fixed $y$.

As $n \mapsto \frac{(\lambda A)^n}{n!}$ is integrable w.r.t the counting measure, we use Dominated Convergence Theorem as $\frac{(\lambda A)^n}{n!}G_n(y)$ is bounded by $\frac{(\lambda A)^n}{n!}$ for all $y$ to interchange the limit and sum and obtain
$$\lim_{y \to \infty } F_Y(y) = \lim_{y \to \infty} \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-\lambda A} \frac{(\lambda A)^n}{n!}G_n(y) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-\lambda A} \frac{(\lambda A)^n}{n!} \lim_{y \to \infty} G_n(y) = 1.$$

Note that we also showed that $F_Y$ is increasing as $G_n$ is increasing.